# About embeding assets(images) in AS3 project

Tags: actionscript-3, sdk, flex4, embed, assets

I am using flex sdk 4.5.1 and flash develop to compile my AS3 project. I have small images, about 12KB which is silly to load them using Loader class, so embeding is better solution.

However when this line at the top of my Main class is uncomented i get blank swf

```
[Embed(source = "../assets/gui/play1.png", mimeType = "image/png")]
private var PlayUpImg:Class;
```

(when i comment it out, the compilated swf is ok)

What could be the error. Why do I get the blank swf?

I am working on pure AS3 project in FlashDevelop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try embing the png image as arbitrary binary data by using the "application/octet-stream" mimetype. Then you would use a `Loader` object's `loadBytes()` method to load the png image's binary data. The following is an example of this:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    [SWF(width="256", height="256", backgroundColor="#FF0000")]
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        [Embed(source = "assets/ie9.png", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
        private var IE9:Class;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.loadBytes(new IE9());
            addChild(loader);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

**[UPDATE]**

I know this answer has already been accepted but here's an extra added bonus.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This also works for loading pngs from BLOBs that have been stored in SQLite Db, this is an alternative to simply embeding it in the swf.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the image to the Displaylist:

```
package
{

    import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite{

        [Embed(source = "../assets/gui/play1.png", mimeType = "image/png")]
        private var PlayUpImg : Class;

        public function Main()
        {
            var myImage : Bitmap = new PlayUpImg();
            addChild( myImage );
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Tried that, the swf is still blank white.

Comment: Is it maybe a problem that I work on pure AS3 project. Should I work on FLex 4 project in Flash develop?

Comment: No, that should work. Can you post the image or try another one?

Comment: Tried with other png even with Loader class works, but with Embed directive I still get the whole swf blank. Are possible some misconfigurations in Flex?

Comment: Do I need some flex sdk 4 add-ons? :)

Comment: Or it is some bug in FlashDevelop4

Comment: It seem that flex sdk 4.5.1 has some problems but I don't know. I guess it is very new version. I tried with older version of flex sdk 4.0 and worked just fine. It compiles and show the embeded image. 

So my advise is use the older flex sdk version :)